# What is the equivalent of a Swift completion block in Python?

Tags: python, swift

In Swift we can write a function with a completion block like this:

```
func thisNeedsToFinishBeforeWeCanDoTheNextStep(completion: () -> ()) {
    print("The quick brown fox")
    completion()
}
```

And then when we call it, we can put something inside of that block to execute once it's finished it's process:

```
func thisFunctionNeedsToExecuteSecond() {
   print("jumped over the lazy dog")
}
```

What is the equivalent in Python?

Comment: Python functions just execute in order.

Comment: All code executes in order. So even if it's an API call, it won't progress to the next line until the previous function has received a response? And what if I want a function to begin executing, but want the program to continue while it works, once that function has finished I want it to execute something else?

Comment: Unless you use mutlithreading, the functions will execute in order.

Comment: @spacemonkey "And what if I want a function to begin executing, but want the program to continue while it works (...)" *that* would make a great question :)

Comment: Gotchya. Alright, well in case anyone was wondering how you do it with Swift, that's the code for it above :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python considers functions as objects, meaning you can pass them around (like in Swift, although I'm less familiar with the implementation details in Swift). You can't specify a type in the parameter, of course, since you can't do that with anything in Python, but that's okay. The implementation would look like:

```
def do_first(completion):
    print("The quick brown fox ")
    completion()

def do_second():
    print("jumped over the lazy dog.")
```

And then to use them:

```
do_first(do_second)
```

Unless you use asynchronous code ahead of the `completion()` call in the first function, the lines will execute sequentially as expected.