# Completion handling in Firestore Python

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to python and firestore. But I have some experince on Firebase. I go through the [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) doc for python. I dont know how to find if task completes successfully or completes with some error. Normally other languages have completion block.

For example I want to know if write completed with success or error for following code:

```
resp = doc_ref.set({
u'first': u'Alan',
u'last': u'Lovelace',
u'born': 1915
})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the [reference](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/index.html) for firestore python client. It explains what result an operation returns, what errors it may raise etc.

For example, below is a snippet from the [reference](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/document.html#) for Documents-

> **create(document_data)** Create the current document in the
> Firestore database.
>
> **Parameters**:   document_data (dict) – Property names and values to use
> for creating a document. Returns: The write result corresponding to
> the committed document. A write result contains an update_time field.
>
> **Return type**:  google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.types.WriteResult
>
> **Raises**:   Conflict – If the document already exists.

You can have try except blocks to capture and handle errors in relevant cases.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172180/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-swift-completion-block-in-python) is an SO post explaining what is a python equivalent of swift completion blocks.